# error while building neo4j source code

Tags: build, build-process

I'm trying to build Neo4J , I have downloaded the source from github: neo4j-master.zip 
containing the source,

```
 when i build this I hit upon following errors. tried to find out in google but
```

couldn't relavant details, I'm new to this product and i'm sure I have missed something 
related to .git can any one help me if identifing this problem . Thanks in adavance.

```
Messages from Maven:

[INFO] Neo4j ............................................. SUCCESS [8.300s]
[INFO] Licensing configuration ........................... SUCCESS [3.338s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel ..................... FAILURE [2.371s]
.
.
.
.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.4:rev
ision (generate-git-hash) on project neo4j-kernel: .git directory could not be f
ound! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

I'm using mvn clean install command for initiating the build.

```
Regards,
Aslam.
```

Comment: If any one has come across this issue, do let me know where i'm going wrong. this is stalling my progress. Thank you.